# Django AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My question seems similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661112/attributeerror-usermanager-object-has-no-attribute-create-superuser), but the answer and explanation did not seem adequate, so I'm going ahead with a custom auth_user_model issue that is beyond my understanding. My app/users/model.py is like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager,AbstractBaseUser)
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password,name=''):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, password
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            name=name
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self,email,password,name=''):
        user = self.create_user(email,name=name,password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,default='')

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name if self.name else self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_superuser
```

My stack trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 50, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 149, in handle
           self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
 AttributeError: 'MyUserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'
```

I cant for the life of me figure out why this error is occuring. I'm using Django 1.9.1, with Python 2.7.11, with pydanny's cookiecutter django module. Relevant installed apps include djstripe, and allauth. Djstripe mostly works under these conditions, but I am unable to create a superuser, or login to the admin area.

At a loss here, so I hope a Django jedi can steer me in better direction, with some type of explanation. Thanks

Comment: Could there be a problem with indentation? Are you perhaps mixing tabs and spaces?

Comment: i doubt it; the code executes w/o an indentation error

Comment: But if the entire `create_superuser` method was somehow indented within the `create_user` method, you wouldn't get an indentation error; nor if it was  somehow outside the class.

Comment: @Daniel - you sir, are a genius!! i ruled out tabs/spaces errors bc i thought I'd hand-typed all of the code, forgetting that there was one snippet copied from the django docs. That's the sneakiest error I've ever encountered w/Python. I'll look into preventing that from ever happening again, bc I though I'd solved that issue by setting my tmux and vim editor preferences to not allow both tabs and spaces for indentation. Again, brilliant answer