# 'BaseUserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We have a django application with a custom user model

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
```

the model is also registered in settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

When attempting to create a new user using

```
python manage.py createsuepruser
```

I get the following error

```
  File "D:\APP\webapp\backend\webserver\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\APP\webapp\backend\webserver\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\webdev2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\webdev2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\webdev2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\webdev2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute     
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\webdev2\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\webdev2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle     
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
AttributeError: 'BaseUserManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'
```

Comment: where is your model manager? add your User model manager here.

Comment: And add settings for Auth_Model

Comment: See the following from the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @Amirbig is a implementing a custom UserManager necessary when inheriting from AbstractUser? (according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33671088/1794792 it isn't)

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL is set to CustomModel. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @wjh18 do I need to implement a custom UserManager if I inherit from AbstractUser?